# target specific line of text in <p> before <br>

Tags: html, css

I'm running some edits on another person's site and they're asking if I can edit the first line of a repeatable p element.  Here's an example of what was built:

```
<p>
Cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id.
<br>
Cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id.
<br>
Cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id.
</p>
```

So my question is - without having to change or add to the HTML, am I able to target the first line of text with css?

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first-line` pseudo element can do that, but check for browser compatibity here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line

```css
p::first-line {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id.
  <br>Cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id.
  <br>Cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id.
</p>
```

Comment: oh dear... thanks for that @pugazh, had a brain meltdown there and completely forgot that existed!